# Way to eliminate external commands from scriptfor generating NMEA 0183 xor checksum using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, checksum

I recently had the need to generate and verify NMEA 0183 checksums using bash and I couldn't find much written to accomplish exactly what I needed.

NMEA 0183 sentences start with a $ and end with a * and two characters which are a hex xor of all the bytes between the $ and *.  Example:

```
$INGGA,230501.547,2118.97946,N,15752.60495,W,2,08,1.1,5.17,M,,,0,0001*02
```

This utility will convert a string to hex and xor it.  It can be used to verify already existing checksums, or generate checksums for the end of NMEA sentences you are generating (it strips out the $ and *.. from strings you feed it.)

```
#!/bin/bash

# =========================================================
# Reads a NMEA 0183 sentence and calculates the proper
# XOR checksum for the end.

# Will accept a string with or without a checksum on
# the end or $ on the front and calculate what the checksum
# should be.

# Sentence can be read as an argument but must be single quoted
# or preceded by a \ or the shell will try to interpret the
# talker as a variable and the result will be incorrect.
# Examples:

#     xor '$INHDT,207.7,T*27'
#     xor \$INHDT,207.7,T*27
#     xor INHDT,207.7,T

# If run with no arguments, will prompt user for data.  No
# quotes or backslash is needed then.

# Depends: xxd sed

# ===T.Young 09/2016=======================================

set -o pipefail
set -o errexit
set -o nounset

# Functions
# =========

depcheck() { # Checks that necessary external commands are present
             # and executable
    local DEPENDS="sed xxd"
    for PROG in $DEPENDS; do
        [[ -x "$(command -v $PROG)" ]] || {
            echo "$PROG MISSING!  Exiting."
            exit 0
            }
    done
    }

x_or() { # Here is where the magic happens
    # The next two lines strip out $ characters, or an
    # * and anything after it (checksum)
    HEAD="${SENTENCE%\**}"
    TAIL="${HEAD//\$}"

    # Convert ASCII string into hex and read into an array.
    # Each element in the array gets preceded by "0x"
    HEXVAL="$(xxd -pu <<< ${TAIL})"
    HEXARRAY=($(printf '%s' "${HEXVAL%0a}" | sed -e 's/../0x& /g'))

    # Loop through the array and do the xor, initially start $XOR at 0
    for (( x=0; x<"${#HEXARRAY[@]}"; x++ )); do
        XOR=0x$(printf '%02x' "$(( ${XOR:-0} ^ ${HEXARRAY[$x]} ))")
    done

    # Strip off the 0x from the result
    CLEAN=${XOR#0x}
    printf '%s\n' "${CLEAN^^}"
    }

main() {
    case "${1:-}" in
        "")  # No input specified, read from stdin
            depcheck
            read -r SENTENCE
            x_or
            ;;

        *) # Input was provided, use that
            depcheck
            SENTENCE="$1"
            x_or
            ;;
    esac
}

# Main
# ====

main "$@"
```

When shell scripting I always try to find ways to eliminate use of external programs, even ones as common as sed, or xxd.  If anyone knows a way to do the above using only shell builtins please chime in.

Update:  Here is a new function taking Sato's method into account.  It allows for the complete elimination of external program calls, and the associated depcheck function above.

```
x_or() { # Create a hex XOR checksum of all the bytes
    # Clean the line of $ character and anything before it
    TAIL="${SENTENCE##*$}"
    HEAD=${TAIL%\**}
    LEN=${#HEAD}

    # Loop through the string and do the xor
    # initially start $XOR at 0
    XOR=0
    for (( x=0; x<$LEN; x++ )); do
        (( XOR^=$(printf '%d' "'${HEAD:$x:1}'") ))
    done

    printf '%02X\n' "${XOR}"
    }
```

Call the function with "LC_CTYPE=C".  There is probably still more that could be done here but this is fairly succinct.

Comment: Since this site is for questions and answers only, I'd suggest you split your post into quest and answer parts. I've done so myself before. Also, asking to find gotchas is not ourbl job here. There is code review stackexchange site, so you might ask it there. Otherwise your post is risking to be closed

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid this isn't how the site works. If you want to share something you found or wrote (which is a great thing to do), please ask a question to which your solution would be an answer and post that solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd do it like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

log() {
    {
        printf '%s: ' "${0##*/}"
        printf "$@"
        printf '\n'
    } >&2
}


cksum() {
    tot=${#1}
    let len=tot-4

    let res=0
    while [ $len -gt 0 ]; do
        let res^=$( LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d' "'${1:$len:1}'" )
        let len--
    done

    let ptr=tot-2
    if [ x"$( printf '%s' "${1:$ptr}" | tr a-f A-F )" != x"$( printf '%02X' $res )" ]; then
        log '%s: invalid checksum (found %02X)' "$1" $res
    fi
}


check () {
    if expr "$2" : '\$.*\*[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]$' >/dev/null; then
        cksum "$2"
    else
        log 'invalid input on line %d: %s' "$1" "$2"
    fi
}


let cnt=0
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        let cnt++
        check $cnt "$1"
        shift
    done
else
    while read -r str; do
        let cnt++
        check $cnt "$str"
    done
fi
```

The shebang line claims `bash`, but it should still work for `ksh93r` and `zsh`.  No dependence on `xxd`.  No claim to be an example of scripting style to be followed, either. :)

Comment: Oh this is great.  I was going to make something along these lines my question... Is there a way to get rid of the external commands calls to sed and xxd?  I also like the use of LC_CTYPE=C.  I'll have to learn more about that one.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use tr to uppercase a-f instead of creating an intermediate variable and using ${VARIABLE^^}?

Comment: @TrevorYoung Sort of: I'm using `ksh93`, and `^^` isn't supported.